# Error when compiling RGBDSLAM for Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the RGBDSLAM ros competition entry to compile on my 32 bit ubuntu 10.10 machine. I am compiling it on a fresh (today) version of diamondback but get the following lines when trying to compile using step 4 (after following the previous steps) of the guide...

phil@phil-Latitude-E6400:~$ rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/phil/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110302-125811
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['rgbdslam']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

I can get data from the kinect and view in rviz, after following the relevant wiki guides. Have I missed something simple?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9255/error-when-compiling-rgbdslam-for-kinect/) by [philnoonan](https://answers.ros.org/users/223/philnoonan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you download the sources for the rgbdslam? It seems rosmake is unable to find the package. You should add the path to the sources for rgbdslam to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. I tried using rgbdslam on diamondback with kinect and you also need to make some adjustments to the code to make it compile. But even then it seems that the image message from openni_camera has changed and rgbdslam can't do anything with it.

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on 2011-03-02**:
Personally I don't use the setup.sh file for anything else than starting kinect. In my normal shell I added export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=path/to/my/ros/stuff:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to my .bashrc. That way I can have everything pretty independent.

**Comment by [philnoonan](https://answers.ros.org/users/223/philnoonan/) on 2011-03-02**:
But I don't know if I changed the correct file as it didn't seem to do anything (I changed the setup.sh file in opt/ros/diamondback). I then copied the two rgbdslam folders into opt/ros/diamondback/stacks which had some success until ros_nobuild failed due to a permission error.

**Comment by [philnoonan](https://answers.ros.org/users/223/philnoonan/) on 2011-03-02**:
I did download the sources, which got placed in /home. I added the destinations to the setup.sh file so that the line read export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/phil/ni/ni:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks:/home/phil/freiburg_kinect-experimental:/home/phil/hogman_minimal.